# How to use ln-transformation with loads of zeroes?

Tags: data-transformation, logarithm, zero-inflation

I came across a method of ln-transforming exogenous variables in non-negative data sets with loads of zeroes in a lecture. With the method proposed, one simply ln-transforms the variable in question and later replaces former zeroes with zeroe again. Additionally, a dummy is created that indicates zeroes.

Let me give you an example I will conjure up with Stata:

```
*Use some random data here

clear all
set more off
sysuse nlswide1.dta

*Generate ln-transformed variable (I know it makes no sense here, but that is not the point)
gen ln_collgrad68 = ln(collgrad68)

    *Replace generated missings with zeroe
    replace ln_collgrad68=0 if collgrad68==0

    *Generate dummy indicating this procedure
    gen null_collgrad68=0 if collgrad68>0 & collgrad68!=.

    replace null_collgrad68=0 if collgrad68==0
```

Despite the example being totally random, the idea should come across. I understand that the procedure above is a way to avoid missings - especially in zeroe heavy data. I however have the following questions:

(1) I have never seen this before and can't find it in the standard literature. Where can I read up on this procedure?

(2) What do you think are the pro's and cons?

(3) What you recomend this procedure?